# Can someone help me to get Ubuntu Touch on my Lenovo a706

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I really want to get Ubuntu Touch on my phone. I'm a very big fan of Ubuntu and I was really dissapointed, that I can't get it. I've read porting guide and found opensource code of lenovo a706, but I don't know what to do with it.
I've tried to ask in many forums, but I've got no answers so far.

Please, help me to get this OS ported on my device, cause I can't do it on my own :(